# How to transmit tv channels from a real tv to the Internet?

Tags: streaming, live-streaming, television

I recently came accross over some tv-streaming sites and tried to understand the technology. And I just don't get it.

Scenario:

I have 500 TV Channels from the cable company, that I also pay for. Now I want to transmit each channel to a streaminghost and make each channel separately accessible for anyone. People just choose from a dropdown list the TV-Channel they like. How do I get the 500 Channels into my computer, send each channel as a seperate stream to ex. ustream.com und embed each channel in a website? I just don't get it how people do that exactly. Can someone explain me the technology behind it?

Comment: Well, for starters, you would need *all 500 channels* running at your house at the same time.  The bandwidth from the cable company to your house probably can't support that.  Then you'd need to *double that* by streaming them back out over your internet connection.  The physical wires connecting your house to the various data grids in your area don't support what you're asking.  In order to accomplish this, you'll need to make significant investments in communications infrastructure.  And the cable company might be curious why you're doing it...

Answer (score 0):

Aereo does this. The [legality is currently in question](http://www.csmonitor.com/Business/Saving-Money/2014/0512/Supreme-Court-case-could-have-major-implications-on-TV-s-future). It may also not be available in [your area](https://aereo.com/coverage).

https://www.aereo.com/

Comment: Thank you so much Jeremy. I'll have a look at that.

Comment: The Supreme Court today ruled against Aereo, and it's current business is now illegal. http://www.theverge.com/2014/6/25/5801052/aereo-supreme-court-ruling